# Wordpress: How to have a responsive full screen image?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I don't want a background image, just an image on the homepage (with elements before and after the image) that will display full screen on every device. I don't want the user to have to click on the image to see it full screen. (I'm using the Harmony theme.)

Comment: And I have no idea either why the post itself is contained into a limited portion of the screen http://vnavon-gestalt.fr/

Answer (score 0):

Here goes the code how you can full screen image on every device but this code may be cause to stretch your image ...

```
img {
   width:100%;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

**NOTE: First remove all containers before you do that**

Comment: Whatever value I give at width and height, whether 100% and 100 vh or pixel values, the image does appear different inside the preview, but not on the final website : http://vnavon-gestalt.fr/

Comment: I mean it changes the way it appears on the website, sorry, but it always stand inside a certain limit on the screen, and never goes full screen

Comment: If you are using an editor .. you have to fullwidth that row in which you have added image

Comment: I can't find find the right part of the CSS, do you have an idea what I'm looking for ? I've used Firefox's inspector to check, but I'm not clear enough about how to use it I guess… sorry this sounds like a very easy question but I feel like I can spend hours on it again without seeing the light… http://vnavon-gestalt.fr/

Comment: U are using an editor .. Just GO in the row option and there I think you'll find an option to full width row or full width content .. If not then let me know the name of that editor

Comment: actually using the editor is fine, the point is that there are 95 various "row" mentions ; I've tried them one by one, changing their width to 100% when it was not already (except a few media queries for small screens, as I'm on a computer right now and just wanted to look for the right paragraph to change), but none of them passed the image to full screen

Answer (score 0):

Add class "img-responsive" under img like `<img class="img-responsive" src="">`

This will work only if you have used bootstrap framework in your theme html.